# Terraform list output generates invalid Json syntax

Tags: terraform

I have two outputs that produce lists

```
output "subnets" {
value = aws_subnet.xy[*].id
}

output "elasticsearch-endpoint" {
value = aws_elasticsearch_domain.es_vpc[*].endpoint
}
```

outputs have a trailing comma

```
[
  "subnet-...83c738af",
  "subnet-...45ffb11b",
]

[
  "vpc-....eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com",
]
```

Is this a bug, or what can I do to get rid of this comma?

Comment: It's not a bug because the default isn't JSON format. Wrap the output in `jsconencode` if you want it to be valid JSON.

Comment: Since ECMAScript 5 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas trailing commas are valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the ticket https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/13025

And there is also the solution

```
terraform output -json my_list
```

With the -json parameter the output is valid

```
[
  "subnet-..83c738af",
  "subnet-..45ffb11b"
]
```